# My function recreates a cookie even if it already exists

Tags: php, setcookie

Hello I have a problem.

I am using the below function to create a cookie when there is no one available.

The problem is that when the browser has been closed an opened again, this function creates the Cookie again...even if it is already there.. So everytime the user opens and closes the browser, this cookie gets created and created again..

This is really bad for me. How do I avoid this issue?

What 's wrong in my function?

Thanks

```
 <?php
  function GenerateTuittingID()
  {
      $todaydate = date('Ymd');
      $time = mktime(date('G'), date('i'), date('s'));
      $NowisTime = date('Gis', $time);
      $random_numbers = substr(number_format(time() * rand(), 0, '', ''), 0, 10);
      $random = $random_numbers . $todaydate;
      if (!isset($_COOKIE["tuittingID"])) {
          setcookie("tuittingID", $random, mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015));
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: the cookie can **never** be created again and again -- if it already existed then it will get overwritten, other wise if it does not exist it will be created. make sure you browser does not clear cookies when closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open your browser settings, go to `Privacy`.

2) Click on `Use custom settings for history`.

3) Make sure the drop down beside `Keep Until` say `They Expire`. If not, update it and press okay.

4) Let me know if that solved your problem.

**Edit** (Just saw your comment)

Set the path and domain on your cookies so they are accessible from the whole site:

```
setcookie("tuittingID", $random, mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015),
  '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with your code

- problem is in user's browser
- there is another problem in another part of your script

Comment: No there must be a problem. The cookie is not recognized at all after the browser has been closed. It get recreated and recreated again. The only function I use is this. So the problem is here. Looks strange to me the problem is in the browser. I am on Firefox 5 for mac...

Answer (score 1):

The cookie can **never** be created again and again --

If it already existed then it will get overwritten, otherwise, if it does not exist it will be created. make sure you browser does not clear cookies when closing.

Comment: I found the problem!! one is under www, the other one is without www..How do I solve this issue?